# Log custom header X-API-KEY from nginx to Graylog

Tags: nginx, graylog

I have an nginx (1.12.1) server running on VPS#1 and I have Graylog running on VPS#2. All sys + nginx logs are sent to Graylog.

To get nginx working I've had to install the [nginx content pack](https://marketplace.graylog.org/addons/572ff823-62cc-468e-af17-300bcfd9932d) from Graylog Marketplace.

I had to add the following to nginx.conf:

```
log_format  graylog2_format  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" <msec=$msec|connection=$connection|connection_requests=$connection_requests|millis=$request_time>';

access_log syslog:server={redacted}:12301 graylog2_format;
error_log syslog:server={redacted}:12302;
```

I followed the instructions and everything works like it should. I receive all logs from nginx.

What I want to do now is also send along the header X-API-KEY, that nginx receives, to Graylog.

I've tried adding `"$http_x_api_key"` to `log_format` in nginx.conf, like so:

```
log_format  graylog2_format  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_x_api_key" "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" <msec=$msec|connection=$connection|connection_requests=$connection_requests|millis=$request_time>';
```

But this results in none of the nginx logs to be sent to Graylog.

What else can I try?